# Javascript interpretation of shallow copy?

Tags: javascript

Reading through [this article](https://we-are.bookmyshow.com/understanding-deep-and-shallow-copy-in-javascript-13438bad941c) containing this statement:

```
var employeeDetailsDuplicate = employeeDetailsOriginal; //Shallow copy!
```

Is that considered a shallow copy in javascript?

Comment: No, that's considered an assignment of a reference from one variable to another.

Comment: That article is incorrect. I would seek a new source of information.